# vector-matrix multiplication in r

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I want to multiply 1000 random variables to a matrix so as to get 1000 different resultant matrices.

I'm running the following code :

```
Threshold <- runif(1000,min=0,max=1)    #Generating 1000 random variables so that we can see 1000 multiple results of Burstscore
Burstscore <- matrix(data=0,nrow=nrow(Fm2),ncol=ncol(Fpre2))
#Calculating the final burst score
for (i in 1:nrow(Fm2)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(Fpre)){    #Dimentions of all the matrices    (Fpre,Fm,Growth,TD,Burstscore) are 432,24  
{
  Burstscore[i,j]= ((as.numeric(Threshold))*(as.numeric(Growth[i,j]))) + ((1-(as.numeric(Threshold)))*(as.numeric(TD[i,j])))
}
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error -

```
'Error in Burstscore[i, j] = ((as.numeric(Threshold)) * (as.numeric(Growth[i,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length'
```

Comment: Not reproducible, we don't have access to `Fm2` object.

Comment: @Pascal We do. The other two matrices in the equation are directly dependent on Fm and Fpre variables. These variables were earlier used in the code and have same dimensions.

Comment: We = potential helpers.

Comment: @Pascal Oh i get it. Sorry. But the main problem here is how do i run this loop so that it returns me 1000 resultant matrices.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But when asking a question on SO, you are asked to provide a minimal reproducible example. This helps to understand the context, the format of data you use and what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put in one cell of the Burstscore matrix 1000 values (as you are multiplying each [i,j] one by the entire "Threshold" vector). Apart from this, your code contains unnecesary elements (brackets or `as.numeric()` statements). And, of course, as said above, it is not fully reproducible, and I had to "invent" several matrices.

I *guess* that what you want to do is the following:

```
Threshold <- runif(1000,min=0,max=1)
Growth <- matrix(runif(432*24), ncol=24)

Burstscore <- vector("list", length(Threshold))
for (i in 1:length(Threshold)) {
    Burstscore[[i]]= (Threshold[i]*Growth) + ((1-Threshold[i])*TD)
}
```

In R, it would be even more elegant to use a `lapply()` function:

```
Burstscore <- lapply(Threshold, function(x) (x*Growth)+((1-x)*TD))
```

Finally, I suggest you also put a more meaningful title to your question, so it could potentially be helpful to others also.

Comment: Exactly! I want want 1000 matrices as my result. Thanks in Advance :)